# How to calculate the user's average rating on all his/her nodes with Fivestar?

Tags: php, drupal-7, rating, drupal-fivestar, computed-field

On my website, users can rate each other's nodes via a Fivestar field called *Stars* in a comment. I'd now like to calculate the overall average score of a user. That means, I'd like to display the user's average score for all his/her nodes.

For example. Let's say a user created 2 nodes: *Node 1* and *Node 2*. Some people rated his content:

- Scores of *Node 1*: 4/5, 5/5, 3/5
- Scores of *Node 2*: 4/5, 4/5

The overall average would then be (4+5+3+4+4)/5=4.

Preferably, this result should also be displayed as stars.

How can I do that?

---

**Edit:** Working with the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module seems to be a general idea to solve this matter. It looks fine to me and I think it's best to store the users' average score in a user field, in order to make it easily accessable. (Working with a view is also fine.) I'm planning to display the average score on their profile page, but perhaps I'm going to use it elsewhere on the website in the future too.

Can you please help me with (a scetch) of the code I'm supposed to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas4019 provided a great solution at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95617/how-to-calculate-the-users-average-rating-on-all-his-her-nodes-with-fivestar. Thanks again for all the efforts!